# jQuery selected menu item and tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

Page in question - http://brettcolephotography.com/services.html

My jQuery current-menu-item-highlighted code doesn't work with my tabbed page if the user arrives at a specific tab (each tab has a discrete url) by following an external link

I have this bit making my current menu item stay underlined, works great in general

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bcp-nav a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

I'm using the EasyTabs (by Alfa Jango) implementation of jQuery tabs, also works great. If you use the main nav and go from one page to the service pages, services becomes underlined, but if you follow an external link to any of the tabs, services is not highlighted.

example, follow this from here - http://brettcolephotography.com/services.html#photo-licensing

Comment: use `window.location.hash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loc = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');
    $('#bcp-nav a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == loc)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

I've just tested it and it's working.

To stop the page jumping to the ID try using this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  if (location.hash) window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, 1);
```

Comment: Outstanding Joe, thanks, any idea how I could add in a piece that makes the page not be scrolled down when you get there.

Thanks

Comment: @Ursinus - no problem! I've just added a snippet to stop the page scrolling down when a hash is set.

Comment: Do I lump this in with the same bit or is it its own script? Never mind on whether it will affect all pages, I assume since it's dealing with the hash it won't

Comment: You can put that snippet outside `$(document).ready(function(){...});` if you want as it doesn't use jQuery. `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` is only run if there's a hash in the url  so it will run for this link `services.html#photo-licensing` but not for this `services.html`.